# Generate file in memory and serve it to users pc- Django

Tags: python, django, download

The user clicks an **Export** button, a file is generated in memory ( a .xlsx file using openpyxl) and is downloaded to users pc. How do i do this in **Django?**

I'm inside my views.py where say i have **file** which is a openpyxl workbook. Normally u save a workbook from memory to disk like so:

```
file.save('desired-name.xlsx')
```

How do i serve this with Django? Thx!

Comment: @e4c5 u are truelly a king, thx!

Comment: Sigh! I don't get such big thanks when I write longggg answers :-)

Comment: well, u solved my problem and fast, so...:)